# The component doesn't change after clicking on new route

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have created component in Vue which has defined one property userCode. I write this property in html like this `{{this.userCode}}` to ensure property is passed correct.

```
  export default {
    components: {...},
    computed: {...},
    props: {
      userCode: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
       getParam() {
          return {code: this.userCode, ...}
       }
    },
    ...,
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('domain/getAll', this.getParam());
  }
```

I use this component in 2 routes, I have a lot of routes defined in project so I pick just relevant:

```
{
  path: '/user/aaa',
  name: 'users',
  component: userView,
  meta: {
    requiresLoggedIn: true,
  },
  props: {userCode: 'AAA'}
},
{
  path: '/user/bbb',
  name: 'users',
  component: userView,
  meta: {
    requiresLoggedIn: true,
  },
  props: {userCode: 'BBB'}
},
```

And html routes:

```
<router-link tag="li" to="/user/aaa" active-class="active"><a><span>Users AAA</span></a></router-link>
<router-link tag="li" to="/user/bbb" active-class="active"><a><span>Users BBB</span></a></router-link>
```

codes which can be used are only 'aaa' and 'bbb'.

So when I open some view User aaa or User bbb first time data are fetched from server, but when I click on another view of user, data are't fetched. Can you tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `created` hook runs only once and after your component is rendered it won't be called when you will change the route ( you can check it by adding logger inside `created` hook, so you will see that it will be logged once) 
So your component is already in DOM at the point when you are changing the route.

For achieving this goal you need to watch for changes in the router:

```
 watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    console.log('will be fired every time you change the route')
    this.$store.dispatch('domain/getAll', this.getParam());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please, take a look at some articles about Vue lifecycle hooks. These will be quite useful to cover. 
https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/vue-instance-lifecycle-hooks    https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/